# simple messagebox not getting displayed

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to display a message box if the string is empty and this is the code i have tried.i am not getting any errors but still message box is not getting displayed.Any help is appreciated.

```
Dim tmp1 As String, tmp2 As String, tmp3 As String
Dim TextBox1 As String
Dim TextBox2 As String
Dim TextBox3 As String

tmp1 = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value
If tmp1 = " " Then
MessageBox.Show ("file1 not selected")
End If

tmp2 = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.Value
If tmp2 = " " Then 
MessageBox.Show ("file2 not selected")
End If

tmp3 = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.Value
If tmp3 = " " Then 
MessageBox.Show ("file3 not selected")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things

**A**. `If tmp2 = " " Then`

If you are checking for blanks then use this

```
If Len(Trim(tmp2)) = 0 Then
```

**B**. `MessageBox.Show` is VB.Net. For VBA use

```
MsgBox "file1 not selected"
```

Similarly for others...

Comment: thank you so much...can you please tell me why `if tmp2=" " then` didnt work for me?

Comment: Because if there is nothing `""` or more than one blank space `"   "` in the textbox then your `if` condition will not be true.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I recommend you try the following steps:

1. Name three cells in sheet 1 as TextBox1, 2, and 3 - use name manager in Excel (no VBA needed)
2. Type the below code in VBE:

code:

```
If Range("TextBox1").value = "" Then
     Msgbox "pls fill field 1"
End if
```

I hope it makes sense and solves your problem.

Comment: How does this answer the question? :)

Comment: what you suggested is very easy and understandable.thanks a ton :)